# Capybara redirect stderr

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

While running automated test scripts I will oftentimes get the following warning messages and others:

```
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
```

I've searched around and these outputs have nothing to do with my test scripts. They don't impact the results in any way. Thus, I don't wish to see them.

While looking for a way to solve this, I found code which is supposed to redirect stderr to a class which will filter out specific messages. However, when I try to use this code, none of my scripts work.

The class that suppresses the warnings:

```
class WarningSuppressor

    # array to hold warnings to suppress
    SUPPRESS_THESE_WARNINGS = [
        'QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)',
        'QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be     called once.'
    ]

    class << self
        def write(message)
            if suppress_warning? message
                0
            end
        end

        def suppress_warning? message
            SUPPRESS_THESE_WARNINGS.any? { |suppressable_warning| message.chomp.include? suppressable_warning }
        end
    end
end
```

The configuration code that is supposed to redirect stderr:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.default_driver = :webkit
    config.javascript_driver = :webkit
    config.run_server = false # prevents Capybara from booting up a rack application automatically
    config.app_host = 'http://local.xxxxxxxx.com'

    # Sends output to a custom warning supressor
    config.register_driver :webkit do |app|
      Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new(app, stderr: WarningSuppressor)
    end

    # 10 second wait for ajax to finish
    config.default_wait_time = 10
  end
```

If I insert a `binding.pry` in the block statement, `app` is `nil` but `Capybara::Driver::Webkit` exists.

Does anyone have a better way/way to fix this; a method of hiding certain warnings from being displayed while running my automated scripts?

Comment: Having this same issue; did you ever figure it out?